# How to fix a deadlock caused by open

Tags: ruby, timeout, deadlock, open-uri

I have is a deadlock, but I am not using any threads in my program. Plus, the error only happens about once every 1000 to 1500 function calls, making it very difficult to pinpoint and correct.

Here is the complete error message when the issue occurs:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:95:in `join': No live threads left. Deadlock? (fatal)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:95:in `ensure in block in timeout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:95:in `block in timeout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:319:in `open_http'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:737:in `buffer_open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:212:in `block in open_loop'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `catch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `open_loop'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:151:in `open_uri'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:717:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
    from /home/mat/travail_perso/RUBY/MangaScrapp_github/sources/utils.rb:85:in `get_pic'
    from /home/mat/travail_perso/RUBY/MangaScrapp_github/mangafox/MF_download.rb:87:in `page_link'
    from /home/mat/travail_perso/RUBY/MangaScrapp_github/mangafox/MF_download.rb:116:in `chapter_link'
    from /home/mat/travail_perso/RUBY/MangaScrapp_github/mangafox/MF_download.rb:142:in `chapter'
    from /home/mat/travail_perso/RUBY/MangaScrapp_github/mangafox/MF_update.rb:57:in `block in MF_manga_missing_chapters'
    from /home/mat/travail_perso/RUBY/MangaScrapp_github/mangafox/MF_update.rb:45:in `reverse_each'
    from /home/mat/travail_perso/RUBY/MangaScrapp_github/mangafox/MF_update.rb:45:in `MF_manga_missing_chapters'
    from /home/mat/travail_perso/RUBY/MangaScrapp_github/mangafox/MF_update.rb:80:in `MF_update'
    from /home/mat/travail_perso/RUBY/MangaScrapp_github/sources/update.rb:5:in `update_manga'
    from /home/mat/travail_perso/RUBY/MangaScrapp_github/sources/update.rb:15:in `block in update_all'
    from /home/mat/travail_perso/RUBY/MangaScrapp_github/sources/update.rb:14:in `each'
    from /home/mat/travail_perso/RUBY/MangaScrapp_github/sources/update.rb:14:in `update_all'
    from /home/mat/travail_perso/RUBY/MangaScrapp_github/sources/update.rb:22:in `update'
    from ./MangaScrap.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

The link to the complete program is https://github.com/Hellfire01/MangaScrap

The issue happens to the three different methods that use `open`. Here is the one that crashed this time:

```
# conect to link and download picture
def get_pic(link)
  safe_link = link.gsub(/[\[\]]/) { '%%%s' % $&.ord.to_s(16) }
  tries ||= 20
  begin
    page = open(safe_link, "User-Agent" => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}")
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError => error
    puts "Warning : bad url"
    puts link
    puts "message is : " + error.message
    return nil
  rescue => error
    if tries > 0
    tries -= 1
    sleep(0.2)
    retry
    else
      puts 'could not get picture ' + safe_link + ' after ' + $nb_tries.to_s + ' tries'
      puts "message is : " + error.message
      return nil
    end
  end
  sleep(0.2)
  return page
end
```

Here is the link to the file: https://github.com/Hellfire01/MangaScrap/blob/master/sources/utils.rb

I would like to know:

- How can I fix this error?
- If I can not fix this error, are there alternatives to OpenUri that I can use?

Comment: FYI, the reason for a thread error despite using no threads is that the ruby timeout library is being used by net/http (in turn used by open-uri), and timeout uses threads

Comment: Yep, I gessed that much but I still do not know how to fix the issue :/

Comment: [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) is a lot more pleasant to work with than raw Net::HTTP.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I will look into that ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not catching all exceptions here. When nothing is specified after `rescue`, it means that you're catching `StandardError` which is not at the root of Exceptions' hierarchy.

If you want to make sure you're catching **all** exceptions and retry opening a URL (or whatever behavior you'd like), what you want to do is:

```
rescue Exception => error
```