# How do I know what exception to catch?

Tags: ruby, exception

I am dealing with an exception with [this message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883057). It is not a `StandardError`.

I caught it by catching the `Exception` class, but [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173) tells it is a bad solution. How do I determine what exception to catch?

Comment: Look at the source code for your API you are using and catch what exception that method is using.

Comment: If you can reproduce an error you can debug certain exception type.

Comment: Looks like it falls down to timeout so likely to be `Timeout::Error` based on the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html)

Comment: thanks, I will look to see if it is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary add to your code

```
rescue Exception => e
   puts e.class
end
```

And you will know what exception to catch

Comment: thanks, nice tip ^^. One issue tho : I need to let the code run for more than 5 to 8 hours to be able to get it. I will try that and tell you when I get it<br />